# text file and arrayList

Tags: java

I am very new to java and teaching myself.
I need read a Mileage .txt file and store all the data as an ArrayList.Then Process the data to calculate the mileage (miles per gallon) at each fill-up (not counting the first) and print it out.
here is the Mileage.txt
Odometer gallon
91183    12.878
91538    11.007
91884    10.351
92164    9.644
92400    8.125
92812    12.629
93155    10.877
93449    10.317
93751    9.903
94194    13.655

I have been able to read the file and I have the Arraylist, my biggest problem is how to process the arraylist. I was thinking of a for loop after the in.close and processing the mpg but I don't know how to differentiate the gallon from odometer so I can do the Math. Any clues will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than describe your code, why not post it?

Answer (score 0):

> Any clues will be highly appreciated.

Don't put the odometer and fuel usage into a mixed list.  Instead either use separate lists, or create a `Reading` class that has an odometer reading and a corresponding fuel usage value, and create a list of those.